# Screen Freezing Issue with Manjaro and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kde, manjaro

I am facing this issue where the screen just freezes randomly. No relation with anything I am doing. Could be installing a software, could be browsing, could be just listening to music. When this happens, I am forced to force shut down by keeping my power button pressed.
I am currently using Feren OS (based on Ubuntu 18.04) but I faced the same issue with Manjaro also. Both had KDE as the desktop environment. I infact switched from Manjaro due to this issue. I had before tried Feren OS on HDD but didn't encounter this issue however I am facing this issue (for Feren) on installing it on my SSD after removing Manjaro(which already had the issue).
I use and MSI GP63 8RE laptop and have tried nvidia 450 and 435 drivers till now. I checked the ssd for errors using smartctl and it reported no errors. Any help with what is causing this error and how to fix it?
RAM: 16GB
Swap: 8GB
CPU: Intel i7-8750H
GPU: NVIDIA 1060

Comment: Sounds like you might be running out of RAM. KDE has a System Load widget that can constantly show your RAM usage in the taskbar - try putting it there and see if that (or anything else the System Load shows) is the issue.

Comment: No, that can't be the case. I checked the ram usage never crossed 5-6 GB. I have a 16 GB RAM and 8GB swap.